# how to make a guestbook in flash and have it sent to your personal email

Tags: actionscript-2

I wanted to make a guestbook for my flash website but I also need to have it sent to my email. Is there a way I can do this without using PHP or my sql? what would be the as2 for it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**
No, there is not a way to do it without a server-side language.

**Long answer:**
You may be able to do it with `XMLSocket`s by connecting to your SMTP server and then sending the email using the SMTP protocol, but it would be a pain since most SMTP servers don't have a [`crossdomain.xml` file](http://www.crossdomainxml.org/).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to send an email with just ActionScript alone. You can either send the data entered to to a server-side script (PHP or whatever) or you can pop a new email in their email client doing something like this in as2:

```
getURL('mailto:you@yourdomain.com');
```